# PubSub subscribe callback function is not getting the updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, publish-subscribe, aws-amplify

I have a subscribe call back which is getting invoked by a click event. When it happens, the callback needs to check if the customer is logged in. If logged in redirect to the dashboard, otherwise show sign up modal.

Here is my code:

```
const CompA = () => {

  const checkIfAuthenticated = useCallback(() => {
     if (!isloggedIn) {
       openLoginModal();
       // once the user is logged in, isloggedIn will be true. 
       // This is a redux state and it is updating correctly,
     } else {
       redirectToAccountDashboard();
     }
  }, [openLoginModal, isloggedIn]);



  useEffect(() => {
    pubsub.subscribe('xyz',checkIfAuthenticated);
  },[checkIfAuthenticated, pubsub.subscribe]);
}
```

Now my issue is,

1. User clicks 'My Account' link
2. Calls the pub sub subscribe
3. Invoke the callback function 'checkIfAuthenticated'
4. Shows Login Modal
5. Logs in successfully
6. set isloggedIn as true
7. Click again on 'My Account' link
8. Calls the pub sub subscribe again
9. Invoke the callback function 'checkIfAuthenticated'
10. isloggedIn should be true. But it gets the initial state which is
    false - **(This is the issue I am facing. It should get the updated state, true)**
11. Call the pubsub subscribe again from the useEffect
12. checkIfAuthenticated is getting invoked. This time isloggedIn is
    true.
    Appreciate any help.